# How can I use monero-blockchain-blackball to improve my privacy?

Tags: privacy, monero-forks

Monero version 0.12.0.0 shipped with a new executable file called `monero-blockchain-blackball`. What is the purpose of this new program, and how can it be used properly?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`monero-blockchain-blackball` was created to allow a line of defense against other people using Monero with low regard for privacy. In the simplest sense, this tool allows you to ignore others' outputs (containers of money) that are known to be spent in a certain transaction. If you would include these in your transaction as decoys, these decoys would provide little or no protection.

To use this tool, you need to specify the Monero blockchain location and the fork blockchain location. Your Monero download location may be different, especially if you specifically specified a non-default location.

Run the following commands depending on your operating system. Once this command is finished running, you can send transactions that will purposefully avoid using these outputs. Make sure to run the tool before sending sensitive transactions. You must run a full node to take advantage of these benefits at this time.

You can append `--check-subsets` to run a more verbose scan at a cost to performance. You can search only the recent outputs by appending `--rct-only` to save a lot of time and space. You can use `--blackball-db-dir` to save the database to a different location.

#### Linux / MacOS

`monero-blockchain-blackball ~/.bitmonero/lmdb /path/to/other/blockchain/database`

Example: `monero-blockchain-blackball ~/.bitmonero/lmdb /home/monero_fork/lmdb --rct-only`

#### Windows

Open a command prompt in the location of the `monero-blockchain-blackball` file and type in the following, or create a .bat file in the same folder and add the following:

`monero-blockchain-blackball.exe C:\ProgramData\bitmonero\lmdb \path\to\other\blockchain\database`

Example: `monero-blockchain-blackball.exe C:\ProgramData\bitmonero\lmdb C:\ProgramData\monero_fork\lmdb --rct-only`

---

This tool will create a LMDB database with the blackballed outputs in a `data.mdb` file. Unfortunately, you need to convert this file to be read by the wallet software. You will need to follow these steps to convert the database to a list of outputs that the wallet can read.

In order to extract the data, you need to build the LMDB tools. Follow [the instructions on GitHub](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/blob/master/README.md#lmdb) to make the LMDB binaries. Then navigate to `~/monero/external/db_drivers/liblmdb` and run the following:

`./mdb_stat -a /folder/with/blackball/database`

This will show the hash of the database that you have created. Take a note of the database name (eg: `blackballs-418015bb9ae982a1975da7d79277c2705727a56894ba0fb246adaabb1f4632e3`). You will use it in the next step.

You now need to extract the outputs that need to be blackballed. Use **one** of the following:

`./mdb_dump -s blackballs-<hash> /folder/with/blackball/database/ | awk '/[0-9a-f]{64}/{print $1}' > /output/path/file.txt`

`./mdb_dump -s blackballs-<hash> /folder/with/blackball/database/ | grep ^.................................................................$ | tr -d \  > /output/path/file.txt`

The resulting `.txt` file [can be imported into the official GUI and CLI](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/10039/how-can-i-import-a-blackball-database-to-improve-my-privacy/).

Comment: Are there any currently publicly available blackball databases?

Comment: @begs-the-hessian There's nothing official yet, but I put a list I generated up at https://s3.amazonaws.com/monero-legacy-blackball/blackballs.gz