# Permission denied error for monero-blockchain-blackball

Tags: ringdb, monero-blockchain-blackball

I'm attempting to run the monero-blockchain-blackball utility in PureOS, and I'm running into a permission error.

I used the syntax to select the tool, then the Monero blockchain, then a forked blockchain (I'm using Monero v6 for testing). The syntax is described [here](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/8225/how-can-i-use-monero-blockchain-blackball-to-improve-my-privacy).

Upon running the command, I receive the following text:

[image: Failed to create a transaction for the db: Permission denied]

I deleted the `/.shared-ringdb` folder, but the error persists.

How can I fix this permission error?

Answer (score 3):

monero-blockchain-blackball is seeing that the monero v6 blockchain has incorrect block, and is trying to fix it, but the blockchain is opened read only, so it's failing.
This is a bug, since it's expected that the v6 blockchain is borked since people continued mining on it with obsolete software.
Please file this on github.com for the developers to fix it.