# How can I convert a blackball LMDB database into a wallet-readable format?

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, monero-wallet-cli, monero-blockchain-blackball

The resulting file after running `monero-blockchain-blackball` is a `data.mdb` LMDB file. Unfortunately, this file cannot be opened directly by the GUI or CLI. How can I extract the necessary data so that the wallet can read it?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to follow these steps to convert the database to a list of outputs that the wallet can read. I have performed this conversion on Debian/Ubuntu.

In order to extract the data, you need to build the LMDB tools. Follow [the instructions on GitHub](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/blob/master/README.md#lmdb) to make the LMDB binaries.

`cd ~/monero/external/db_drivers/liblmdb`

`make`

Then run the following:

`./mdb_stat -a /folder/with/blackball/database`

This will show the hash of the database that you have created. Take a note of the database name (eg: `blackballs-418015bb9ae982a1975da7d79277c2705727a56894ba0fb246adaabb1f4632e3`). You will use it in the next step.

You now need to extract the outputs that need to be blackballed. Use **one** of the following:

`./mdb_dump -s blackballs-<hash> /folder/with/blackball/database/ | awk '/[0-9a-f]{64}/{print $1}' > /output/path/file.txt`

`./mdb_dump -s blackballs-<hash> /folder/with/blackball/database/ | grep ^.................................................................$ | tr -d \  > /output/path/file.txt`

The resulting `.txt` file [can be imported into the official GUI and CLI](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/10039/how-can-i-import-a-blackball-database-to-improve-my-privacy/).

Comment: For the record, the database name will always be blackballs-418015bb9ae982a1975da7d79277c2705727a56894ba0fb246adaabb1f4632e3 for mainnet, which is what the vast majority of people will need a list for.